# How can implement Local contrast normalization by python or tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, normalization, contrast

I want implement Local contrast normalization by python or TensorFlow.

How can do dis?

Comment: Use `tf.per_image_standardization`

Comment: Here is an implementation of lcn: https://github.com/ejhumphrey/dl4mir/blob/master/dl4mir/common/lcn.py

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov that appears to implement global contrast normalization, if I understand the terminology correctly.